# Adding information to a Layout without having to call it on every controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a layout that is used when you are logged in. `menu.blade.php`.

Then I use it in blade files `@extends('admin.layouts.menu')`

I want to show some information in the layout, let's say the number of messages near the "message" link in the menu. I could easily do this by adding:

```
$message_count = Message::where("user_id", Auth::user()->id)->count();
```

and adding: `<div>{{$message_count}}</div>` to `menu.blade.php`

to every single controller and view where the layout is used, but this is clearly not a clean way to do it.

Is there a way to pass information to the view in a single step instead of having to do it in every single controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers).

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location

Register the view composer within a service provider:

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('menu', function ($view) {
        $view->with('messagesCount', auth()->user()->messages->count())
    });
}
```

Then each time when the `menu` view will be rendered, it will have `$messagesCount` variable with counted messages for an authenticated user.